# rotate html caret doesn't rotate from center using css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've this simple caret to rotate but it doesn't seem to rotate from the centre, what should I adjust?

```
const Wrap = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  background: grey;

  span {
    display: block;
    transform: ${(props) => (props.isOpen ? "rotate(0deg)" : "rotate(180deg)")};
    transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  const [open, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <Wrap isOpen={open} className="App" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!open)}>
      {open.toString()}
      <span>&#94;</span>
    </Wrap>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-jackson-8rdcl?file=/src/App.js:90-541

Comment: as i can see its working fine whenever click its rotating. What is issue ?

Comment: @aviboy2006 it looks weird, it doesn't rotate from the center. try compare with this: http://plnkr.co/edit/myjf0McPccSMRfIp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the dimensions of your element. See screenshots of comparison:

[image]

versus

[image]

Just use another asset.

Example:

```
span {
    display: block;
    transform: ${(props) => (props.isOpen ? "rotate(90deg)" : "rotate(270deg)")};
    transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
}

<span>{">"}</span>
```

[image: Edit cocky-montalcini-mqfjd]

Comment: but this caret look different than the html caret. Is it best to use image or proper svg icon for this case?

Comment: it depends on what you want it to look like. you can use svg like you mentioned

Comment: can make a fixed height on the span make the thing work?

Answer (score 0):

The `span` is actually rotating from the center. But your caret glyph is not in the vertical center of the span because it has a large margin at the bottom: `^`. Set either a fixed height on the span to force the caret down. Or use a glyph that is more suitable.

```
const Wrap = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  background: grey;

  span {
    display: block;
    transform: ${(props) => (props.isOpen ? "rotate(0deg)" : "rotate(180deg)")};
    transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
    height: 13px;
  }
`;
```